# Spring amqp: How can I read MessageProperties in MessageListenerAdapter

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

handleMessage method does not get the message from queue if I add MessageProperties in its signature. It works fine if there is no MessageProperties.

How can I get MessageProperties in handleMessage of MessageListenerAdapter?

```
public class EventMessageAdapter {

  public void handleMessage(MessageProperties messageProperties, Event event)    {
  ...
  String id = messageProperties.getHeaders().get("key");
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't do it with the listener adapter.

Use the newer-style `@RabbitListener` mechanism [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/receiving-messages/async-annotation-driven.html).

You can use various signatures...

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
public void foo(Event event, @Header("foo") String fooHeader, 
           @Header("bar") Integer barHeader) {...}
```

or

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "bar")
public void bar(Event event, Message message) {...}
```

In the second case you can get all the message properties via
`message.getMessageProperties()`.

You need a [container factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/receiving-messages/async-annotation-driven.html). Spring Boot creates one automatically for you if the starter is on the classpath.

Comment: The second option is exactly what I needed. Thank you, sir.

Comment: How to get the headers from the message (not the properties, but the actual headers)? `message.getMessageProperties()` returns the properties.

Comment: When I publish a message from the RabbitMQ Management UI, I put in the "Headers" a simple header, but can't get it in my listener.

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions in comments; it doesn't help others find questions and answers. `message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders()`.

Comment: just in case someone stumbles on this answer, the link to the documentation is broken and one should use this instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven

Comment: Alternate link is also broken.

Comment: I fixed the links in the answer https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/receiving-messages/async-annotation-driven.html